# Python: How to make a non-blocking while-loop?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

How do I make a non-blocking while-loop? I am making a program to control RGB led-strips with my phone using [`mqtt` package](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/). An mqtt command should make Led_Desk[1] `False` but the while-loop blocks everything else including mqtt-subscription.

I've tried threading, async-await, but nothing's worked so far.

```
    while Led_Desk[1]:

        for x in range(1,255):
            GREEN.ChangeDutyCycle(round(x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)

        for x in range(1,255):
            RED.ChangeDutyCycle(round(100-x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)

        for x in range(1,255):
            BLUE.ChangeDutyCycle(round(x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)

        for x in range(1,255):
            GREEN.ChangeDutyCycle(round(100-x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)

        for x in range(1,255):
            RED.ChangeDutyCycle(round(x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)

        for x in range(1,255):
            BLUE.ChangeDutyCycle(round(100-x/2.55,1)*brightness)
            time.sleep(speed)
```

Comment: Do you want to make those color changes happen simultaneously? or sequentially, like you've coded here?

Comment: It's not about the code-snippet itself. The problem is that Led_Desk[1] can never become false because mqtt subscription is blocked. maybe there is a way check manually for mqtt messages from within the while loop?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use threads, where each thread handles one LED. Not an unreasonable solution, but probably overkill for what you are trying to accomplish. I think this can be done in another way, using 1 thread.

```
import time

Leds = [[GREEN, time.clock_gettime_ns(0)], [RED, time.clock_gettime_ns(0)], [BLUE, time.clock_gettime_ns(0)]]

while Led_Desk[1]:
    now = time.clock_gettime_ns(0)
    for led in Leds:
        if led[1] + speed > now:
            led[1] = now
            led[0].ChangeDutyCycle(round(x/2.55,1)*brightness)
```

The idea here is to keep track of how long each LED has been in it's current state. Then continuously check those values, and when they exceed the threshold, toggle them.

You will probably need to tweak both the logic in the `if` statement and the way the times are being assigned to create the flashing pattern you want. But hopefully this is clear enough to serve as a starting point.

Also, the reason (you might have figured this out already) that the original code is preventing the mqtt subscription is because calling `sleep` in those nested for loops in a single threaded program is going to end up sleeping many, many times, sequentially.

Comment: so sleep is blocking mqtt?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping the while loop in a thread and defining 'thread1.daemon = True'. I'm not sure what it does exactly but it allows threads and main loop to run parrallel without blocking.